# Which tool can I use to calculate the best fee for a specific time?

Tags: transaction-fees, mempool, tools

Let's say I'm okay with a transaction to be included in a block in about 24h.
The fee is obviously dependent on the network congestion.
Which (online) tools can I use to calculate the optimal fee given current network activity?

Comment: https://mempool.observer https://mempool.space https://btc.bitaps.com

Comment: I like the btc.bitaps.com. Very nice! Thanks.